# Which directories in an extension get scanned by CiviStrings

Tags: extension, i18n

[CiviStrings](https://github.com/civicrm/civistrings) is a cli tool that scans an extension for translatable strings and generates a .pot file. According to the readme,

> It scans PHP, Smarty, JS, and partial HTML files for references to the ts() function -- and generates a list of strings using gettext's POT file format.

I'd like to know which directories it scans in an extension. I know it will scan files in the `/ang` directory, but what if I place an html file somewhere else, like `/foo/bar.html` - will that file also get scanned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `civistrings` command doesn't have a prescribed list of directories. It takes a list of paths (files or directories) as an input. For example, here's an excerpt of running it against the `api4` extension:

```
[nix-shell:~/bknix/build/dmaster/sites/all/modules/civicrm/ext/api4]$ civistrings $PWD
#: CRM/Api4/Upgrader/Base.php
msgid "Upgrade %1 to revision %2"
msgstr ""

#: Civi/Api4/Service/Spec/Provider/CustomValueSpecProvider.php tests/phpunit/Action/CustomValueTest.php
msgid "Custom Table Unique ID"
msgstr ""

#: Civi/Api4/Service/Spec/Provider/CustomValueSpecProvider.php tests/phpunit/Action/CustomValueTest.php
msgid "Entity ID"
msgstr ""

#: ang/api4/Explorer.html
msgid "CiviCRM API v4"
msgstr ""
```

At time of writing, the scanner will look for `ts()` expressions in any files which match the following:

- File-name ending with `.js` (parsed as Javascript code)
- File-name ending with `.html` (parsed as HTML with embedded Javascript)
- File-name ending with `.setting.php` (parsed as a Civi settings file)
- File-name ending with `.tpl` or `.hlp` (parsed as a Smarty file)
- File-name ending with `.php` or file-content starting with a PHP signifier in the first line (parsed as PHP code)

This arrangement allows you to keep-it-simple in the typical case of a single extension (i.e. "just scan the entire extension and put all strings in one file"). This also allows you to deal with more complicated arrangements (e.g. `civicrm-core` is large and includes several components split among various subfolders). `civistrings` is focused on the technical mechanics of scanning for `ts()` -- and tries to be agnostic about the directory-structure.